# pl/i enterprise dynamically allocate file

Tags: pl-i

I'm trying to dynamically allocate file via

```
OPEN FILE (OUT) TITLE('DSN(XXXXX.XXXXX.MILTEST),LRECL(80)');
```

File is created but the record size is default value. I tried env variable and alternate name with `DD_DDNAME` but keep getting

> UNDEFINEDFILE condition was raised ABENDU4038

Answer (score 0):

Try this to create a new file in Enterprise PL/I:

```
Dcl theLrecl = 42;
 Dcl userDataset char(44) init('USER.DATASET');
dcl fileTitle char(88);                           
fileTitle ='DSN('||trim(userDataset)||'),NEW,CYL,SPACE(1,1),KEEP,LRECL('||theLrecl||')';       

Put Skip List('fileTitle=',trim(fileTitle));  /* optionally show the title for debugging purposes */    
dcl tempFile file print;                          
OPEN FILE(tempFile) title(trim(fileTitle));
```

Note: the 'title' string can not contain whitespace; so trim it to be sure.
More details are at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1PK74015

Oops, misread question; here is the snippet from knowledge centre regarding LRECL;

LRECL
The LRECL option is the same as the RECSIZE option.

LRECL (n) 

If LRECL is not specified and not implied by a LINESIZE value (except for
TYPE(FIXED) files, the default is 1024.

RECSIZE
The RECSIZE option specifies the length, n, of records in the data set.

RECSIZE
512
( n ) -

For regional and fixed-length data sets, RECSIZE specifies the length of each
record in the data set; for all other data set types, RECSIZE specifies the maximum
length records may have.

Full details of both options appear in chapter 6 : using datasets and files of "Enterprise PL/I for z/OS
 - Programming Guide
Version 4 Release 4"

Comment: Your code does not mention the LRECL anywhere - and as I read the question that is where the OP's problem is.

Comment: Fixed the answer (eventually).